# Python for loop declaration and behaviour

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am finding it difficult to understand how the following code works:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(sum(i for i in mylist))
```

the code above gives a correct result of 15, but shouldn't "i" be used after it is declared and not before?

Comment: What you see is — despite the name `for` — not a for loop, but a (generator) comprehension. Like some other special expressions (e.g. ternary if: `x = 3 if foo=bar else 5`) it has this "weird" order, because that's how you would say it in English.

Comment: @RobJan Nit-picking here, but: No, that's not a list comprehension

Comment: @L3viathan I admit that this is way to create generator.

Answer (score 4):

Read the documentation on [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

You will see that you are (effectively) creating a mini generator equivalent to:

```
def iter_list(lst):
    for i in lst:
        yield i

myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(sum(iter_list(myList)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is an untyped language.
That means you do not need to declare the variables such as `i`.

You can give a bit more clarity to compiler , and your understanding by doing the edit:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(sum(int(i) for i in mylist ))
```

So, Python is just very smart in giving type to variables, and flexible too as compared to static C code.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case ([list-compherensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) the syntax allows to do so

Answer (score 1):

Because of the Syntax of sum() ... iterable and a start position

`sum(i, start)`

You can take an look with examples there --> https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum